# Is there any concept like google plus app access token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am currently developing an app for Google+. Is there any way to fetch/search public data with out user authentication, I mean, using an app access token

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/activities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#apikey which talks about using an API Key instead of using a user login.

Quoting that page:

> For Google+ API calls that do not need to identify a particular user, you can use your application API key. This is useful for server-side applications, or web applications that do not require the user to sign in with Google.

[...]

> After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter `key=yourAPIKey` to all request URLs. The API key is safe for embedding in URLs; it doesn't need any encoding.

You can get the API key via the new Developers Console by going to http://console.developers.google.com/ and selecting your project, then clicking on the `APIs & auth` tab on the left and then `Credentials`. There should be a section on the right **Public API Access** with a button to press to create a new key if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Still no luck,

Here is the response :

Array
(
    [url] => https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/activities?query=stackoverflow&maxResults=100&orderBy=recent&key=54XXXXXXX4723.apps.googleusercontent.com
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 390
    [request_size] => 262
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.813163
    [namelookup_time] => 0.411874
    [connect_time] => 0.454496
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.605186
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 9
    [speed_download] => 11
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.813109
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

```
[primary_ip] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.XXX.XXX.XXXX
[local_port] => 52227
[redirect_url] =>
```

)

Answer (score 0):

The answer around the key is correct for general public access. However, the URL you are using is not correct. You want the activities list API I suspect: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}/activities/public?key={YOUR_KEY}